# AWS Codebuild .NET Core building docker image

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, aws-codebuild

We tried the default AWS codebuild image to build .NET core apps and it worked fine.

Now we require to build to Docker images, but the default image has no docker installed.

AWS has the option to run the Builder image in Priviledged mode so you can run docker-in-docker operations.

I would like to know if there is an image I can use that has both .NET Core and Docker installed, so I can build the code, and then the image.

Thanks!!

Comment: I don't know that much about the AWS codebuild environment but you can use a help docker-container in which you can build your code and later create a new image from it. So you need a build-container with .NET installed to perform the build instead of installing .NET on the host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create you own docker image and provide that to CodeBuild (as part of project environment configuration).

You can find CodeBuild's vended docker images here for reference  https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images

You need to create a docker image which has both docker daemon and .NET core on the same image. Refer to this sample on how to start the docker daemon before starting builds in your custom docker images http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-docker-custom-image.html